# What percentage of Lithium compounds pass the blood brain boundary?

Tags: human-biology, nutrition, psychiatry, blood-brain-barrier

I've been doing some research on lithium. Lithium is used in psychiatry as a medicine for mania and bipolar. This is generally a high dosage of lithium carbonate, with around 300mg of elemental lithium per dose.
It is also available as a dietary supplement for example as lithium orotate, with a standard dosage being 5mg elemental lithium.

I have seen statements that the ion that the lithium is bound with has an effect on how much of the lithium in the salt is able to cross the blood brain barrier. For example, that lithium from lithium orotate is able to cross the blood brain barrier more readily than lithium from lithium carbonate.

Is there any data on the percentage of lithium from different lithium compounds which is able to cross the blood brain barrier?
Primarily I am interested in lithium carbonate and lithium orotate, but it seems that lithium citrate and lithium aspartate are also common so data on any other lithium compounds are also of interest to me.